# How to display Image protected by Authorization Header in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I created a NextJS App which displays images.

To get images I need an Authorization Header with Bearer Token. I have it and it's working when trying with postman.

But how can I display this image in a `<img src="..." />` in my NextJS app?

The app is Server Side Rendering, but I think I need to "use client" to make it work?

When I create a Blob, I still have "net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)", but the Token is good:

```
const [path, setPath] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    const src = 'http://example.com/test.jpg';
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 123456',
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
        },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-store',
        method : "GET"        
    };
    fetch(src, options)
    .then(res => res.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        const toBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setPath(toBlob)
    });
}, [])
```

The blob generated like "blob:localhost:3000...". is not working. Maybe because of 401 error? How can I display an Image protected by the Auth Header?

Thanks